# Finding maximum element corresponding given conditions in a list

Tags: algorithm

I have a list of elements with coordinates and a value:

```
element: {x, y, value}
```

All values are distinct.

Then I have a list of queries that ask for the element with the highest value, whose horizontal or vertical distance to given point A is less or equal than `r`.

```
abs(element.x - A.x) <= r && abs(element.y - A.y) <=r
```

X-coordinate of point `A` in query `Q(i)` will always be greater or equal to x-coordinate of point `A` in query `Q(i-1)` (points A are ordered ascending)

I have already made an algorithm, that sorts elements by their x-coordinate and then has two iterators denoting an interval of elements in the list, that correspond to given condition, but I does not work fast enough.

Time complexity should be O(log(n)) for every query at most.

EDIT:

Pseudo code for my current algorithm:

```
list = {element1, element2, element3, element4 ... }

// sotring by x-coordinate
sort( list, by_x_coordinate )

begin = list.begin
end = list.begin

for every query Q(x,y) {

    while end.x > x+r {
        end = end + 1
    }

    while begin.x < x-r {
        begin = begin + 1
    }

    //  element we are looking for is now somewhere between begin and end

    // we loop over all elements with potentially greatest value 
    max = -inf
    for i = begin to end {
        if (list[i].y <= y+r) && (list[i].y >= y-r) {
            if list[i].value > max {
                max = list[i].value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It has the time complexity of O(n*q) in worst case scenario, but O(q+n) in best case scenario.

Comment: Can you write your pseudo code? It's not very clear what are you asking. 
What is a list? linked list? array? what type are the values x,y,value? where are they stored?

Comment: Just looking up all the elements in the array and filtering them should have O(n) complexity. If the data is already sorted, you can exploit it and reduce the cost, but if the data is not sorted and you can't keep it sorted, your best bet is to just filter all the data.

Comment: Container type and data types don't matter, I am looking just for an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Could you reverse sort the list of elements, based on the value, High -> Low.
Then find the first match that satisfies the x/y -> r condition you want?

Comment: I think this is a comment not an answer

Comment: Yes, I could, but that would have the time complexity of O(n) for every query in the worst case scenario.